# Search string with Javascript and return next string

Tags: javascript

I have a response from a description API in the form of a string, I verify it in this way:

```
let product = 'Producto:';
let text = jsonDesc.plain_text;

console.log(typeof text);
```

Response = `String`

```
console.log(text)
```

Response = `Producto: Mesa con 4 sillas para todo tipo de restaurante, bar, cafetería, cocina y negocios en general.`

So I'm looking for a specific word like this:

```
let product = 'Producto:';

let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];
```

But it returns the following message on console:

`**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Can not read property '1' of null**`

But if I do it this way with a hard-coded string:

```
let textTest = "Producto: Pack de 4 Sillas para bar.";

let resultProduct = textTest.match(new RegExp (textTest + '\\s(\\w+)')) [1];
```

`console.log (resultProduct);` 'Pack'  Is correct!!

Do you know what is it due to? And how do I solve it from the string response from the API?

Comment: Sorry. I already corrected it.

Comment: Thank you! It's much more readable now

Comment: If you were meaning to use `\s` and `\w` to match whitespace and word characters, they should be together with their backslashes - `\ s` in a regular expression will just mean an unnecessary escape character (for a literal space), followed by a literal `s`. (same thing for `w`)

Comment: eg maybe you wanted `product + '\\s(\\w+)'` (if you also want to avoid having to double-escape the backslashes, you can use `String.raw`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry the spaces were when copying and pasting but I already edited it. Thank you.

Comment: @OscarDev `let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];` this produces "Mesa", and doesn't crash like you state

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/01v8hbt3/

Comment: That's right, it works as long as it is hard-coded but this data is obtained from an API response. I use async and await. What makes me strange is that when I make a console.log of the variable that contains the string, it gives me the correct answer but when searching for the word it tells me the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```js
const jsonDesc = {
    plain_text: 'Producto: Mesa con 4 sillas para todo tipo de restaurante, bar, cafetería, cocina y negocios en general.'
}

let text = jsonDesc.plain_text;
console.log(`typeof text: ${typeof text}`);

const product = 'Producto:';

const resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];

console.log(`resultProduct: ${resultProduct}`)
```

Comment: That's right, it works as long as it is hard-coded but this data is obtained from an API response. I use async and await. What makes me strange is that when I make a console.log of the variable that contains the string, it gives me the correct answer but when searching for the word it tells me the error.

Comment: The fact that the string came from an API response or the use of async/wait should be irrelevant to this. I think the string back from the API response is not what you think it is. How about comparing in the code your hard coded string with the API response string using === operator. You are assuming this will return true, but from what you are saying I think it will be false.

Comment: Exact friend  I tried your code and works great! One additional question Do you know how to return the following words to find a point on text?

Answer (score 2):

You said:
    Do you know how to return the following words to find an end point?

I am not sure, but this might be what you are after. It returns:

```
con 4 sillas para todo tipo de restaurante, bar, cafetería, cocina y negocios en general.
```

```js
const jsonDesc = {
    plain_text: 'Producto: Mesa con 4 sillas para todo tipo de restaurante, bar, cafetería, cocina y negocios en general.'
}

let text = jsonDesc.plain_text;
console.log(`typeof text: ${typeof text}`);

const product = 'Producto:';

const resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)'))[1];

console.log(`resultProduct: ${resultProduct}`)

const afterThatPart = text.split(resultProduct)[1].trim()

console.log(`afterThatPart: ${afterThatPart}`)
```